# Loading CSV file in R loads a NA observation as the last dataset. Why does this happen?

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I was working on the titanic dataset from kaggle and have noticed there is a missing/blank observation loaded at the end of the dataset as can be seen in the screenshot

Dataset loaded into R using read.csv
[image]

Dataset loaded into R using read_csv
[image]

I used two ways to see the difference but both have loaded in the same way, by having the last row/observation in the dataset loaded into R as NA. One visible difference is that read_csv has loaded all the variable values of last observation as NA where read.csv has only done for a few of them.

```
titanic_original_read_csv <- read_csv("titanic_original.csv", col_names = TRUE)

titanic_original_readcsv <- read.csv("titanic_original.csv", header = TRUE)
```

I have checked the csv file and it has 1310 rows including the column header. So, when it loads into R it should only have 1309 observations.

Why has NA loaded as the last observation in the dataset I loaded? Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Probably a blank line at the end of the file - very common if the data have come from excel at some stage. Just filter it away.

Comment: You can of course check the actual text file, see what's at the bottom. Or do `r <- readLines("titanic_original.csv");r[length(r)]`

Comment: @RichardTelford oh hmmmm, I am new to R so was thinking may be I didn't specify any parameters in the read function which lead to this.

Comment: @RemkoDuursma > 
I received this warning but cant find anything fishy in the csv file

r <- readLines("titanic_original.csv");r[length(r)]

Warning message:
In readLines("titanic_original.csv") :
  incomplete final line found on 'titanic_original.csv'
[1] ",,,,,,,,,,,,,"

Comment: @RemkoDuursma I deleted the last row and this fixed it. so the best way it run readlines everytime and check the file is proper from R side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

r <- readLines("titanic_original.csv");r[length(r)] response provide by @RemkoDuursma helped to identify that there was an incomplete line at the end of the csv file.

The original file was in xlsx format but I had saved it as csv and tried to load using read_csv function. But during this conversion some how an incomplete line got added up.

Well mostly said was that it was a conversion issue and was suggested to use read_excel function to load xlsx files and avoid converting xlsx to csv anytime.